# Windows phone development, Buttons in Pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, pivot

I'm developing windows phone 8 project.  I use a `pivot` as a `Pager`.

Making the question easy to understand, assume that I have two pages.  There are 4 custom buttons(usercontrol) in each page.  When I click a button, I set the button's `isSelected` property to true, and the other 3 buttons `isSelected` property to false.  Of course, if the `isSelected` is true, the button will be highlighted.

The problem is, this only works in `page two`, and not work in `page one`.  No matter which button I click in page one, nothing happened.

This is my code:

1.the `SelectedIndex` property of my usercontrol is binding to a datasource.

```
SelectedIndex ="{Binding selectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

2.when the buttons in this usercontrol are clicked, I change the `SelectedIndex` property.

```
private void OptionButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = ((WCCSelectableButtonImageText)sender).IntTag;
    SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

3.this user control is added to a pivot.

Anybody know the reason?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a binding issue? SelectedIndex should start with capital letter in the XAML.

```
SelectedIndex ="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It's not the capital letter problem.  selectedIndex is the property of data.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the reason.  In the custom Usercontrol, I have a field to save the 4 buttons.  The weird thing happened because it's `static`.

```
public static List<WCCSelectableButtonImageText> OptionButtons;
```

I change it to:

```
public List<WCCSelectableButtonImageText> OptionButtons;
```

It works fine.